# How to create a validation plugin for web application using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a validation plugin for web application which evaluates the form when only the form-id is passed to the plugin using javascript/jquery

This is the code i have written where i have used the name of each field to evaluate the input for the html page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#formId').validate({
            rules: {
                    'Name': {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3
                    },
                    'Email': {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    'password': "required",
                    'Confirm_password': {
                        required : true,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    },
                    'test': {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'Radio': { required: true },

                    'ddl': {
                        required: {
                            depends: function (element) {
                                if ('none' == $('#select_field').val()) {
                                    $('#select_field').val('');
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  },

                messages: {
                    'Name': {
                        required: "Enter the name",
                        minlength: "The name should be atleast of 3 characters "
                    },
                    'Email': {
                        required: "Enter the emailid",
                        minlength: "The emailid should be atleast of 5 characters"
                    },

                    'test': {
                        required: "Check atleast one box"
                    },
                    'Radio':
                     {
                          required:"Please select an option<br/>"
                     },
                    'ddl':
                        {
                            required: "Please select an option from the list"
                      }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) { 
                alert('valid form submitted'); 
                return false;
            }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You should add what you tried so far

Comment: What part of the validation are you having problems with? Any relevant code would be useful.

Comment: why not to use validate.js?

Comment: Is this even a *valid* question?

Comment: What is the specific problem or question? What isn't working as expected? See [ask].

Comment: I have to perform validation based on the input type (textbox , radio button, drop-down list) so that the plugin can be used on any form to validate the input. Here, i have used the name of each field and so this code is specific for a html page. I want to generalize it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jquery Validation plugin.

[Read this](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)